AWS Appconfig deployments targeting users or groups
I've started exploring using AppConfig to introduce feature flagging for my app. It's not the most full-featured tool on the market, but AWS is an easier sell to management than LaunchDarkly or similar.
One feature I really liked from almost all other feature flag platforms is the ability to release changes to specific users or groups of users. While AppConfig has some support for canary deployments, I don't see any straightforward way to support enabling flags on a per-user basis.
Has anyone had any luck with this or should I just accept that this is unsupported functionality.
